# Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: int, boolean

```
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
DWORD PID = -1;
BOOL found = FALSE; BOOL EL_DenyProcessAccess(void);
// Do Windows things;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
// Get all processes
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
```

Keep getting Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: What includes do you have? On what line is the error?

Comment: #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
 and it is saying the error is line 28

Comment: And which line is the 28th in your original code?

Comment: 27 main(int argc, char const *argv[])
28  {

Comment: then simply try with int main or void main! I was expecting something later on and harder to find...

Comment: int main being preferred

Comment: oh wow how did i overlook that, super rusy at this. Int main worked. Ty for your time and help.

Comment: you're welcome! And likely should delete the question, to not get voted down ;-)